What is the process for obtaining a power of attorney from someone who is in prison?
If someone is incarcerated, what is the process for obtaining a power of attorney from them to handle their affairs?

Friends in prison looking to rope you into doing shady stuff are neither friends nor, unfortunately, in prison. This is a scam, walk away.

Questions asking for legal advice (i.e. advice which is specific to your situation) are off-topic here. I edited the question to make it generic and to remove irrelevant details. Also, note that you can't "be" a power of attorney. You can "have" a power of attorney or "be" an attorney.

@littleadv It depends. Lots of inmates, especially for minor felonies or for misdemeanors, still have some affairs that have to be managed by someone, such as dealing with a car, working out issues for a landlord or mortgage company, dealing with an inheritance from a deceased relative, liquidating assets to pay a lawyer or bail bond company, filing tax returns, dealing with Social Security or with medical bills that were outstanding when one was arrested, etc. It is the norm for someone who was arrested to not have their affairs entirely in order at the time.

@JBentley Indeed. The preferred term for someone who grants someone a power of attorney to handle their affairs is a "principal" and the preferred term for someone given that power is an "agent" or "power of attorney agent" or "attorney-in-fact". This said, the mostly less educated working class language of "being a power of attorney" is fairly commonly used and generally understood. The word "attorney" used to mean agent under a power of attorney, but now means in a meaning derived from the original meaning, an "attorney at law" (i.e. a lawyer) when used without modification.

united-states
The most straight forward way would be to have an attorney at law who is also a notary present it for signature to the inmate in prison. Attorneys at law in the places where I have practiced joking call their bar admission card a "get into jail card" because unlike family, an attorney is generally allowed to met in person, face to face, with an inmate without being separated by glass or plexiglass from the inmate, and can bring legal documents and pens (carefully accounted for, so they aren't left behind to fashion into weapons) into a visit with an inmate.
In a super maximum security prison, it may be necessary to bring a crayon in lieu of a pen. The notary can sign and stamp the document immediately after the visit after having seen it signed by the inmate in person, although the notary will probably still need to bring in a notary journal to be signed by the inmate with the same writing instrument, in addition to the document to be signed.
In lower security prisons, family and a notary could bring the POA document and a pen into a visiting area where they can meet at a table, or could have the guards pass those to the inmate to sign and return in sight of the notary and under the watchful eyes of the guards (which isn't a concern since a power of attorney signing normally isn't attorney-client privileged). Check with the prison officials in advance.
Often, in either case, it is necessary to schedule a visit with an inmate well in advance, and various circumstances (e.g. a lockdown due to an incident involving other inmates, or a disciplinary incident with the inmate that you want to visit) can postpone the visit without notice or warning. When the inmate is incarcerated far from his or her family or attorney, who must travel for many hours to visit, this can be a hardship.
It also pays to confirm in advance with a phone call to the inmate when allowed, or a letter, that the inmate is willing to sign the proposed power of attorney, as it is a fair amount of trouble to get this arranged, and you don't want to be disappointed and have the inmate refuse to sign it after you go to the trouble to make the arrangements. But never forget that all phone calls and letters to the inmate, except attorney-client privileges communications, are monitored and recorded by prison officials. So, don't discuss anything that could be used in some way by prison officials or prosecutors against the inmate.
Another piece of practical advice for people, especially attorneys-at-law and notaries, who visit people in prison, is that you should wear something that it is O.K. to get dirty, rather than a nice suit, because there are often incidents that come up in a prison visit that will soil your clothes. Furthermore, dress with the expectation that you are likely to be searched at a level similar to a TSA (Transportation Safety Administration a.k.a. airport security) "being pulled aside" physical pat down search.
Also, don't bring anything into the visit that would be contraband such as cell phones or pocketknives or anything that could be used to pick the lock on a handcuff or anything that could be mistaken for drugs, and come sober and not under the influence of any drug.
Footnote on terminology
The preferred term for someone who grants someone a power of attorney to handle their affairs is a "principal" and the preferred term for someone given that power is an "agent" or "power of attorney agent" or "attorney-in-fact". This said, the mostly less educated working class language of "being a power of attorney" is fairly commonly used and generally understood. More than a century ago, the word "attorney" meant agent under a power of attorney, but now means in a meaning derived from the original meaning, an "attorney at law" (i.e. a lawyer) when used without modification.
Sources
I don't practice criminal law and have never had to visit an incarcerated inmate myself. But I've practiced law in law firms and office shares with lawyers who do. This answer is based upon the stores and lore that they have shared in casual water cooler type conversation with them.

england-and-wales
The process for granting an ordinary power of attorney ("PoA") is reasonably straightforward.
As provided in Section 10 of the Powers of Attorney Act 1971, the donor of the PoA just needs to issue a document in the form contained in Schedule 1 or "in a form to the like effect but expressed to be made under [the] Act":

This General Power of Attorneyis made this day of 19 by AB of
I appoint CD of
[orCD of and
EF of jointlyor
jointly and severally] to be my attorney[s] in accordance with section
10 of the Powers of Attorney Act 1971.
In Witness etc.,

(Note: I've copied this verbatim from the schedule even though it contains typing errors and formatting issues).
You can also add restrictions on the power if you don't want it to be unlimited e.g. "This power of attorney is restricted to the power to [list of permitted actions or matters to be handled".
Section 1(1) requires that the PoA be executed as a deed. The requirements for deeds are set out in Section 1 of the Law of Property (Miscellaneous Provisions) Act 1989. The document needs to state that it is a deed and it needs to be signed by the donor of the power "in the presence of a witness who attests the signature [or] at his direction and in his presence and the presence of two witnesses who each attest the signature". It also needs to be delivered as a deed. A deed is "delivered" at the moment there is an intention by the donor for it to become legally binding. There is a common law rebuttable presumption that a deed is delivered when it is dated.
This answer makes some assumptions:

The donor only wishes the donee to handle their affairs while they have capacity i.e. it's an ordinary power of attorney which is needed. This power of attorney will cease to be effective if the donor loses capacity. If the donor wants someone to handle their affairs when they lack capacity, they need a lasting power of attorney under the Mental Capacity Act 2005. Creating a lasting power of attorney is a more formal process than an ordinary power of attorney.
The donor isn't trying to delegate any powers they hold as a trustee of a trust. If they wish to do that then the power of attorney needs to be issued under Section 25 of the Trustee Act 1925.
Pursuant to Section 10 of the Powers of Attorney Act 1971, the donor is only trying to delegate "anything which he can lawfully do by an attorney". This would preclude for example voting in an election, or rights of audience at court.


@brhans I rejected the edit (even though it seems like a reasonable improvement) because the quoted passage is copied verbatim from the legislation, including the typing errors.
